# Using Bazel with local boost installation

Tags: c++, boost, bazel

I would just like to know if someone has tried doing this?

I am currently using nelhage/rules_boost for my boost dependencies(just to make some things compile for the meantime), but since the code I'm working with is only 100% compatible with 1.55 I cannot use his rules for long.

I could also try adapting his code to work with boost 1.55, but I think it would make it a lot easier if I just make Bazel depend on an installation of boost since I am also working with containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use boost as pre-built external dependency with Bazel. I just reference the local installation in my `WORKSPACE` file and then create a `BUILD` file for it, e.g.:

```py
# WORKSPACE file
new_local_repository(
  name = "boost",
  path = "/your/path/to/boost",
  build_file = "third_party/boost.BUILD",
)
```

In the `BUILD` file you can choose to split headers and libs into separate rules or combine them together. In the following example I keep all the headers as a rule and separate libraries into different rules:

```py
# third_party/boost.BUILD
cc_library(
    name = "boost-headers",
    hdrs = glob(["include/boost/**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    includes = ['include'],
)

cc_library(
    name = "boost-atomic",
    srcs = ["lib/libboost_atomic.a"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "boost-chrono",
    srcs = ["lib/libboost_chrono.a"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

...
```

Then in my binary/library I pick-up the dependencies:

```py
cc_binary(
  name = 'main',
  srcs = ['main.cc'],
  deps = [
    '@boost//:boost-headers',
    '@boost//:boost-regex',
  ]
)
```

This should also work is you have boost installed into `/usr/include` / `/usr/lib`, but I haven't tried to be honest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try this soon. :)